# How should I store and manipulate data to report on?

Tags: python

Below is a slightly simplified example of a "pattern" I tend to use here and there.

```
class Indicator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = []

    instances = {}

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, date, hour, hostname, action):
        if (date, hour, hostname, action) in Indicator.instances:
            i = Indicator.instances[(date, hour, hostname, action)]
        else:
            i = cls()
            Indicator.instances[(date, hour, hostname, action)] = i
        return i

    def add_data_point(self, foo):
        self.list1.append(foo)

    def get_avg(self):
        return sum(self.list1) / len(self.list1)

Indicator.get_instance("2015-01-01", "12", "host1", "foo1").add_data_point(23)
Indicator.get_instance("2015-01-01", "12", "host1", "foo1").add_data_point(-5)
Indicator.get_instance("2015-01-01", "12", "host1", "foo1").add_data_point(12)
Indicator.get_instance("2015-01-01", "12", "host1", "foo1").add_data_point(6)
Indicator.get_instance("2015-01-01", "12", "host2", "foo1").add_data_point(2322)
Indicator.get_instance("2015-01-01", "12", "host2", "foo1").add_data_point(-52)
Indicator.get_instance("2015-01-01", "12", "host2", "foo1").add_data_point(232)
Indicator.get_instance("2015-01-01", "12", "host2", "foo1").add_data_point(34)

for indicator_id in Indicator.instances:
    print('For {0} average is {1}'.format(indicator_id, Indicator.instances[indicator_id].get_avg()))
```

Since this seems to be something I do regularly, I am tempted to believe there is a better/simpler way to do this using python (2.6). Is there?

Comment: I'd recommend to extend ```list``` or ```dict```. The API of your pattern is very similar, except the get_avg function, you can use as extension to Python's classes.

Comment: Perhaps the [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site will be better suited to you. There is no "problem" with the code you provided - you are only looking to improve an already existing process.

Comment: @Lix: interesting site I'll look into it now, but, SO is now about programming _problem_ questions?

Comment: @Lix: further to my previous reply to your comment, why do you affirm that I am looking to improve a process? Can't it just be what I said? That I feel like I am doing something not quite the python way? With a simple answer: either "no you're doing it pretty much how you typically should" (which I doubt, hence my question), or "yes, there is a better, way which is...."

Comment: @isonix - perhaps that is not the best choice of words :P But essentially, yes. I'm not saying that your post does not belong here - just that there might be a *better* place to post it.

Comment: @isonix - essentially the issue here is "better/simpler". These could be considered subjective terms that don't necessarily have concrete answers.

Comment: @Lix: I don't understand why subjectivity is so incompatible with asking a programming question. For pretty much all the narrow enough issues I encounter google will give me the answer, albeit on SO often (although SO makes me lose time with crappy answers too), but then again I need to rely on SO anwsers often because either the docs are not too well written for a new user, or because I am not smart enough to interpret said docs. In any case I fail to see how questions such as this one "pollute" SO.

Comment: @isonix - who said anything about polluting? I'm suggesting a possibly better site for your question. There is simply not enough space in the comments area to convey to you the idea behind good subjective/bad subjective... Luckily for us [an entire blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) was made on the topic :) If you have a few minutes I would highly recommend reading over it - you will benefit in the long run when continuing to use [so]. It's a little old, but still relevant.

Comment: @Lix: Just read that blog post, and I am sorry to say but I really understand it as if my question is "good subjective", but then that is my subjective view on the matter ;)

Comment: @isonix - as long as you are aware of the guidelines of the site you are entitled to your own subjective interpretations! Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be better. Update logic for initializing.

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python


class Indicator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = []

    instances = {}

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, hostname, date="2015-01-01", hour="12", action="fool"):
        if not (date, hour, hostname, action) in Indicator.instances:
            Indicator.instances[(date, hour, hostname, action)] = cls() # you only need to initialize when there is no match
        return Indicator.instances[(date, hour, hostname, action)]

    def add_data_point(self, foo):
        self.list1.append(foo)

    def get_avg(self):
        return sum(self.list1) / len(self.list1)
# use list comprehension to initialize instances    
[i.add_data_point(x) for i,x in zip(map(Indicator.get_instance(), ['host1', 'host1', 'host1', 'host1', 'host2', 'host2', 'host2', 'host2']), [23, -5, 12, 6, 2322, -52, 232, 34])]

for indicator_id in Indicator.instances:
    print('For {0} average is {1}'.format(indicator_id, Indicator.instances[indicator_id].get_avg()))
```